# TabelCell - how do I make the TableCell content only occupy the rest of the screen and wrap

Tags: css, material-ui

The last column is the one that I'm fighting with. If I leave it alone and dont apply any styles to it the content runs off the edge of the screen and I end up with a scroolbar. I want it to wrap instead of generating a scrollbar. When I turn overflowX to "hidden" the content just is not shown at all. My goal is to get the content to just wrap:

```
column 1 | column 2 | column 3                                       |
apples   | are good | apples are good apples are good apples are good| 
                    | apples are good apples are good apples are good| 
pears    | are great| pears are great                                |
```

Right now I've got a hack in place that works but it's ugly and doesn't seem like the right way to do it. The hack is:

```
              <span
                style={{
                  wordWrap: "break-word",
                  display: "block",
                  width: "1000px"
                }}
              >
                {comment.message}
              </span>
```

the whole code is:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  tableWrapper: {
    overflowY: "auto",
    maxHeight: "500px"
  },
  table: {},
  thingOneCell: {
    verticalAlign: "200px",
    width: "225px"
  },
  thingTwoCell: {
    verticalAlign: "top"
  },
  thingThreeCell: {
    verticalAlign: "top"
  }
});

<CardContent>
          <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
            <Table className={classes.table}>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>thing one</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>thing two</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>thing three</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {comments.map(comment => (
                  <TableRow key={comment.id}>
                    <TableCell className={classes.thingOneCell}>
                      {thing.one}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell className={classes.thingTwoCell}>
                      {thing.two}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell classes={{ root: classes.thingTwoCell }}>
                      <span
                        style={{
                          wordWrap: "break-word",
                          display: "block",
                          width: "1000px"
                        }}
                      >
                        {thing.three}
                      </span>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </div>
        </CardContent>
```

I had it working in a previous version so it must be possible but I can not figure out what's broken at the moment.

Comment: not sure if this works, But try adding padding="dense" or "none" to the first two TableCells and padding="default" to the third TableCell.